# Cannot dynamically resize swiftui view to new runtime defined dimensions

Tags: swiftui, resize, geometryreader

I am writing a view with a RectangleView which I would like to shrink of a percentage (let's say 0.8 percent of the current size) every time I tap the RectangleView itself.

Here an example of the view:

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    @State private var buttonHeight: CGFloat = .infinity
    @State private var buttonWidth: CGFloat = .infinity
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Reduce")
            GeometryReader{ geometry in
                VStack() {  // added the Vstack to center the Rectangle within the GeometryReader (known bug)  
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0).foregroundColor(.purple).frame(
                        width: $buttonWidth.wrappedValue, height: $buttonHeight.wrappedValue, alignment: .center).padding(.all)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            let currWidth = geometry.size.width
                            let currHeight = geometry.size.height
                            print(">> geom width \(currWidth)")
                            print(">> geom height \(currHeight)")
                            buttonWidth = currWidth * 0.8 // CGFloat(currWidth * 0.8)
                            buttonHeight = currHeight * 0.8// CGFloat(currHeight * 0.8)
                            print(">> buttonWidth \(buttonWidth)")
                            print(">> buttonHeight \(buttonHeight)")
                            print(">> buttonwidthwrapped \($buttonWidth.wrappedValue)")
                    
                        }
                        
                }.frame(width: geometry.size.width,
                        height: geometry.size.height,
                        alignment: .center)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like the first time I tap the Rectangle I get it resized, but then it does not happen any more when I tap again.

How can i force specific values of the frame without having the View dimensions recalculated by swiftui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need the `GeometryReader` for the initial value. For the rest of the taps just use what you have in the variables.

You can do this by putting the reader in the background.

```
import SwiftUI
struct ScalingRectangle: View{
    @State private var buttonHeight: CGFloat = .infinity
    
    @State private var buttonWidth: CGFloat = .infinity
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Reduce")
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                .foregroundColor(.purple)
            //re-size with initial value by the background and then onTap
                .frame(width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight, alignment: .center)
                .onTapGesture {
                    //Update values on tap
                    buttonWidth = buttonWidth * 0.8
                    buttonHeight = buttonHeight * 0.8
                }
                .background(
                    GeometryReader{ geo in
                        Color.clear
                            .onAppear(perform: {
                                //Get the initial value
                                self.buttonHeight = geo.size.height
                                self.buttonWidth = geo.size.width
                            })
                    }
                )
            
        }
    }
}
struct ScalingRectangle_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScalingRectangle()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, really worked :-)

Comment: @MPira I'm glad it worked. Do you mind accepting the answer? it is the green checkmark above.